# Id customizado em botão de formulário

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho um botão para enviar um formulário

```
<div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit, html: {class: "button"}%>
</div>
```

Mas nenhum dos atributos HTML (`class` e `id`) funcionam, apenas me geram erro na página. Alguém sabe como posso colocar um id ou classe da minha escolha?

Comment: Cara, acho que foi porque você colocou a classe fora da tag. Você tem que colocar essa classe button junto com a classe actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim:

```
<%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```